# Android AsyncTask - One SubClass Per Database Operation?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have an activity for initialising a game, that does multiple selects and inserts from a number of SQLite tables.

I'm trying to understand AsyncTask, but, from all the examples I've read so far, I'm wondering if I am going to have to subclass AsyncTask for every single different data operation I need to do?

For example, my NewGame Activity does the following:

```
1) Insert new player record into PLAYER table
2) Insert new player's pet record into PET table
3) Select cursor of n records from INVENTORY
4) Insert array of ranomly chosen inventory items into PLAYER_OWNED table
5) ....more things of a similar nature
```

There are going to be a few more selects and inserts for various things too, so having an individual subclass for each one is going to get crazy.  Not to mention that there will be about 8 activities for this game, all relying heavily on database reads and writes.

So, basically, how do I best use AsyncTask to carry out a number of different SQLite operations?

Comment: You mind sharing the tutorial you read on this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass parameters to a AsyncTask, even more, if you use nested clases, you can use global variables from inside the AsyncTask class, by using one of the above or both mentioned aids you should be able to use the same class and have it do diferent things depending on the parameter you pass. I see no real need to define multiple AsyncTasks.

You will *need* to define a AsyncTask in every activity.

I wrote *need*, because you really dont have to, but its comfortable to do it this way, and its easy to read/write code, as the AsyncTask is asociated to the activity only. This is of course suposing you use nested clases, I see no point in writing a separate class file just for an AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks, what you describe sounds perfectly sensible. The tutorials I'd read had separate nested subclasses for Read, Insert and Delete data, so I was getting a bit concerned about being overrun with classes.

What you describe sounds perfectly logical.